# Difference between In memory databases and disk memory database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, hsqldb

Recently i heard about the concept of In memory database.

In any type of database we are finally storing the data in the computer,from there our program will get the data .How in memory database operations are fast when compared to the others.

Will the in memory database load all the data from the database into memory(RAM).

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An in-memory database (IMDB; also main memory database system or MMDB or memory resident database) is a database management system that primarily relies on main memory for computer data storage. It is contrasted with database management systems that employ a disk storage mechanism. Main memory databases are faster than disk-optimized databases since the internal optimization algorithms are simpler and execute fewer CPU instructions. Accessing data in memory eliminates seek time when querying the data, which provides faster and more predictable performance than disk.

Applications where response time is critical, such as those running telecommunications network equipment and mobile advertising networks, often use main-memory databases.

In reply to your query, yes it loads the data in RAM of your computer.

**On-Disk Databases**

- All data stored on disk, disk I/O needed to move data into main
  memory when needed.
- Data is always persisted to disk.
- Traditional data structures like B-Trees designed to store tables and
  indices efficiently on disk.
- Virtually unlimited database size.
- Support very broad set of workloads, i.e. OLTP, data warehousing,
  mixed workloads, etc.

**In-Memory Databases**

- All data stored in main memory, no need to perform disk I/O to query
  or update data.
- Data is persistent or volatile depending on the in-memory database
  product.
- Specialized data structures and index structures assume data is
  always in main memory.
- Optimized for specialized workloads; i.e. communications
  industry-specific HLR/HSS workloads.
- Database size limited by the amount of main memory.

Answer (score 8):

**MySQL offerings**

MySQL has several "Engines".  In all engines, actions are performed in RAM.  The Engines differ significantly in how good they are at making sure the data "persists" on disk.

**ENGINE=MEMORY** -- This is *not* persistent; the data is found only in RAM.  It is limited to some preset max size.  On a power failure, all data (in a MEMORY table) is lost.

**ENGINE=MyISAM** -- This is an old engine; it persists data to disk, but in the case of power failure, sometimes the indexes are corrupted and need 'repairing'.  MySQL 8.0 is getting rid of this Engine; MariaDB continues to support it.

**ENGINE=InnoDB** -- This is the preferred engine.  It not only persists to disk but 'guarantees' consistency even across power failures.

**Aria, Columstore, FederatedX, Spider, ...** -- MariaDB supports several other 'Engines', each with a niche market.

Comment: There are several more Engines in MariaDB.  MySQL 8.0 will have a Temp table engine.

Comment: What's the point of mentioning MySQL engines here? Nearly all RDMS' have in-memory storage choices however the question is just about the concept.

Comment: @Lashae - MySQL's `MEMORY` does not load from disk.  (A user _could_ do that himself.)  The 8.0 note points out that a potential use for "memory" is handled in a special way in that new version.  OK, maybe mentioning MyISAM and InnoDB is digressing.

Comment: Further update:  8.0 seems to have vacillated on what to do with temp tables.  I hesitate to say anything until the dust settles.

Answer (score 2):

In-memory db usually have the whole database in memory. (like MySQL DB Engine MEMORY)
This is a huge performance boost, but RAM is expensive and often not persistent, so you would loose data on restart.
There are some ways to reduce the last issue, e.g. by timed snapshots, or replication on a disk database. 
Also there are some hybrid types, with just a part of the db in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are also in-memory databases like Tarantool that can work with data sets larger than available RAM. Tarantool is able to work with these sets because it is optimized for fast random writes, the main bottleneck that arises.